# MySQL Select query for a calculated column that uses previous row value for current row

Tags: mysql, select, partitioning, mysql-8.0, recursive

I am stuck at this. Trying to help PM team to translate a calculation from Excel using a MySQL select query to do reporting. Your help is appreciated.

Table has 3 columns - Employee, Month, Salary. Need a MySQL Select statement that also creates a new calculated column Bonus (per employee per month) as below (Logic for the calculated column is in Logic column for reference) :

[image: Sample]

Comment: Add your sample data as formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO code (of course w/o Logic column).

Comment: See `LAG()` and other windowing functions.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *,
       CASE month WHEN 1 THEN salary
                  WHEN 2 THEN LAG(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY employee ORDER BY month) + 10
                  ELSE        LAG(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY employee ORDER BY month) + 15
                  END bonus
FROM datatable
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the logic for Month>2 should be previous value of the Bonus column, and not Salary column.

Comment: @Vineeth Sorry, I miss this point. In this case you'd use recursive CTE.